# FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm starting to work with the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. I want to use it in conjunction with an external C# library (mtgdb.info). I installed mtgdb.info to my solution using the package manager and added appropriate using statements when I called methods from the library.

The solution builds without errors or warnings, but when I try to debug the code I get the error listed in the title on the first line that calls a method in the external library. Installing the mtgdb.info nuget package is the first change I've made to the solution after creating it.

The mtgdb.info.dll is referenced in every project of my solution as well as its dependent dll (newtonsoft.json)

Any thoughts on why the solution wouldn't be able to find the assembly at runtime? Are there any good resources on how assemblies are located for Windows Phone applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of the time, this problem appears on x64 machines.

Go to Properties in your project, then go on "Build".
I Guess "platform target' is set on  "Any CPU"

try to put x86 and see if you still have the problem.

Reason is that, when you let "any CPU" on a x64 machine, Runtime will try to find the x64 release of the dll

But if the dll has been compiled for x86 only, Runtime don't find it.

**EDIT :** my bad, i didn't saw first that it was regarding System assembly. Did you install Framework 4.5 ? if not do it, or In :
project => properties => Application => Target Framework : change to a lower value. Anyway i'm surprise you get that error !

PS : With "System" assembly, you can keep "ANY CPU", Microsoft compiled it for 64 & 86 machines of course ;)

Comment: I've tried targetting both x86 and ARM solution-wide with no luck.

Comment: double checked, and I do have .NET 4.5 installed

Comment: And what is you start a  new fresh console project in 4.5 ? if this one works, open its .csproj file, search for the line with `<Reference Include="System"` then compare it with your .csproj file

Comment: It works fine in a blank console app, but adding the reference manually didn't help in the Windows Phone app. Could this be because the API wasn't developed to be compatible with Windows Phone?

I really appreciate your consistent responses, thanks!

Comment: i'm not skilled with Windows phone, i guess the answer is yes. Perhaps the solution is simple : remove the reference to System. I'll generate lots of error. Then add the reference to Windows Phone System. I guess this assembly is a light release of the PC System assembly.

Comment: Seems to be working, I'm going to go ahead and give you credit for this answer anyway, 95% of the time the stuff you mentioned will be the issue.